# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` works on mysql but fails with SQL Server 2008 R2.
What is the equivalent syntax?

Comment: http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/03/01/how-to-create-table-in-mssql-only-if-it-does-not-exist/

Comment: Actually this is not a duplicate of the marked question. This question is asking how to create if it does not exists. because we need a `GO` after create, we cannot put the create command inside `BEGIN` and `END` block, as the answer for other question suggests.

Comment: @JNK, when you where marking this question as basic, your link might have been on top of the search results. however on this date, this question is on top of Google search.

Comment: @Bistro it doesn't matter at all which question is higher ranked in google results. It matters which came first. This Q can still point to the original.

Comment: @Bistro And you definitely CAN do it inside a `BEGIN...END` block if you use dynamic sql.

Comment: IF not exists(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME=YOUR TABLE NAME') begin //DO YOUR STUFF// end

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of a different question. The logic behind it being closed is like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/206570) in reverse. You’re telling the asker that they should have asked `Y` when they’re actually asking `X` (whereas in the XY problem the asker asks `Y` when they’re trying to solve `X`). I.e., the asker did the right thing and the question is closed? *sad face*

Comment: @binki If you think it's not a duplicate, you can nominate it for reopening.  I totally agree with you; this question isn't identical.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne I barely got [3000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) 14 hours ago. **Now** I can vote to reopen ;-).

Comment: @binki That's hilarious!  I had, of course, totally forgotten about the... uhm... odd...  rep system stackoverflow has.

Answer (score 274):

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='cars' and xtype='U')
    create table cars (
        Name varchar(64) not null
    )
go
```

The above will create a table called `cars` if the table does not already exist.

Comment: Better yet - use the specific `sys.tables` catalog view instead of having to remember what obscure `xtype` a table is...

Comment: @marc_s:  Yes.  Another good way :o)  In fact, probably a better way.

Comment: Since this is the top question for this topic in Google even though it has been closed: `if not exists (select * from sys.tables t join sys.schemas s on (t.schema_id = s.schema_id) where s.name = 'myschema' and t.name = 'cars')
 create table myschema.cars (
        Name varchar(64) not null
    )`

Comment: Coming back to this in 2017:

`IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Cars', N'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE dbo.Cars (Name varchar(64) not null);
END;`

Comment: @hastrb, i think you should convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: @hastrb Please make your answer as separate rather than having in comment. It really makes more sense and very elegant solution and after so many years pro devs are looking for this hidden solution. Thanks

Comment: @sanpat the question is locked up, unfortunately.