# error for using a keyword as column name while pushing data from python using pyodbc to sql server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

```
cnxn = pyobdc.connect(...)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sql = 'create table if not exists tab1 (id integer primary key, entry varchar (200), exit varchar (200))'

cursor.execute(sql)
cnxn.commit()
```

in the above code, the query "sql" has the keyword "exit" as a column name which throws up an error. I therefore made the change of enclosing the keyword in quotes like

```
sql = 'create table if not exists tab1 (id integer primary key, entry varchar (200), "exit" varchar (200))'
```

and even tried

```
sql = 'create table if not exists tab1 (id integer primary key, entry varchar (200), `exit` varchar (200))'
```

Which still gives me the error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Serveer Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '"'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

or accordingly,

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Serveer Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '`'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Please help me understand how to overcome this problem without having to change the column name, thanks!

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` syntax.

Comment: As for the keyword, don't use (reserved) keywords for object names; it's bad practice. Use a different name.

Comment: Finally, for the last error, the backtick (`\``) isn't a delimit identifier in T-SQL. T-SQL's delimit identifier are brackets (`[]`), or you can use the ANSI delimit identifier double quotes (`"`).

Comment: `create table if not exists` works for all the other tables. while I know it is a bad practice to use reserved words for object names, in this particular instance, it is a client engagement requirement. please help me get around this problem.

Comment: *"works for all the other tables"* I doubt this; again, SQL Server does *not* support `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. If that syntax is supported, you aren't using SQL Server.

Comment: my bad, my query reads `if not exists create table...`. and thanks, enclosing it in brackets works!

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS CREATE TABLE`, followed by a table definition is also not valid T-SQL syntax.

Comment: Just to note that if you are using SQL Server >= 2016 you could change your workflow a bit to first drop the table if it exists, then create it. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tab1` followed by your create table statement like `CREATE TABLE tab1(...`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, firstly SQL Server does *not* support `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520999/create-table-if-not-exists-equivalent-in-sql-server) for specific answers on that.

Next your second statement. This *won't* generate the error you describe. In fact, if you do try to run it, you get the errors:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
> Incorrect syntax near 'tab1'.

Again, this is because of comment 1. If you try the latter statement, with the backticks (`) you get the same identical errors, you don't get the error about the backtick. Though, as I also mentioned, the backticks are not a valid delimit identifier in T-SQL. Either use T-SQL own, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI SQLs, double quotes (`"`).

Finally, to fix the problem, just don't use a reserved keyword for your object name. Perhaps something like this:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tab1') IS NULL CREATE TABLE tab1 (id integer PRIMARY KEY, UserEntry varchar (200), UserExit varchar (200));
```

Comment: @charlieface I intentionally made it a "one-liner" as the OP was using them in their application code as one-liners too.

Comment: Ah OK sorry. It's just unreadable though. Could use `"""` quotes and put newlines inside the string.